# Please suggest me good algorithm for video segmentation based on changing background?

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation, video-processing

Iam having 1 min video.I need to cut the video into 5 segments depending on changing background.Please suggest me good algorithm which can be easily implemented in matlab.Please provide me helpful links.

Comment: Do you need to cut the frame up into 5 segments or the video up into 5 parts? Can you give an example of the changing background?

Comment: Total there are 2145 frames in my video.I shooted 1 min video with 5 different backgrounds for my project.I need to break total number of frames just like 500 frames for 1st background,500 frames for 2nd background,500 frames for 3rd background,500 frames for 4th background,145 frames for 5th background.

Comment: Actually i need to detect faces in video.Video shooted within room for 10 seconds,outside room for 10 seconds,in park for 10 seconds and so on...